# select-string with multiple conditions with powershell

Tags: powershell, multiple-conditions, select-string

I'm looking for a way to find 2 different lines in a file and only if those 2 line exist I need to perform a task.
So far this is my code

```
$folderPath = c:\test
$files = Get-ChildItem $Folderpath -Filter *.txt
$find = 'stringA'
$find2 = 'StringB'
$replace = 'something to replace with string b'
if ($files.Length -gt 0  ) {
    $files |
    select -ExpandProperty fullname |
    foreach {
        If(Select-String -Path $_ -pattern $find , $find2 -quiet )
        {
            (Get-Content $_) |
            ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $find2, $replace } |
            Set-Content $_
            write-host "File Changed : " $_    
        } 
    }
}
else {
    write-host "no files changed"
}
```

Currently if I run it once it will change the files but if I run it again it will also notify me that it changed the same files instead of the output "no files changed"

Is there a simpler way to make it happen?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Select-String` cmdlet selects lines matching **any** of the patterns supplied to it. This means that the following file contains a match:

```
PS> Get-Content file.txt
This file contains only stringA

PS> Select-String -Pattern 'stringA', 'stringB' -Path file.txt
file.txt:1:This file contains only stringA
```

Passing the `-Quiet` flag to `Select-String` will produce a boolean result instead of a list of matches. The result is `$True` even though only one of the patterns is present.

```
PS> Get-Content file.txt
This file contains only stringA

PS> Select-String -Pattern 'stringA', 'stringB' -Path file.txt -Quiet
True
```

In your case, Select-String chooses all the files containing either `'stringA'` or `'stringB'`, then replaces all instances of `'stringB'` in those files. **(Note that replacements are also performed in files you did not want to alter)**

Even after the replacements, files containing only `'stringA'` still exist: these files are caught and reported by your script the second time you run it.

One solution is to have two separate conditions joined by the `-and` operator:

```
If (
    (Select-String -Path $_ -Pattern 'stringA' -Quiet) -and
    (Select-String -Path $_ -Pattern 'stringB' -Quiet)
)
```

After this the script should work as intended, **except** that it won't report `"no files changed"` correctly.

If you fix your indentation you'll realise that the final else clause actually checks if there are no `.txt` files in the folder:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $Folderpath -Filter *.txt
...
if ($files.length -gt 0) {
    ...
} else {
    # will only display when there are no text files in the folder!
    Write-Host "no files changed"
}
```

The way to resolve this would be to have a separate counter variable that increments every time you find a match. Then at the end, check if this counter is 0 and call `Write-Host` accordingly.

```
$counter = 0
...
foreach {
    if ((Select-String ...) ...) {
        ...
        $counter += 1
    }
}
if ($counter -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "no files changed"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. you helped me a lot.
I don't understand how do I combine the counter ?

Comment: The last code-block in my answer shows how to use a simple counter. I'm not sure if I can be more clear than that? Set `$counter` to 0 outside the loop, inside the loop, whenever the `if` condition is true, increase the counter by 1. Finally, once the loop is done, check the value of the counter with a different `if` expression. It's a rather common programming pattern.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [equatorialsnowfall's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73192737/45375), which explains the problem with your approach well, with a streamlined, potentially more efficient solution:

```
$folderPath = c:\test
$searchStrings = 'stringA', 'stringB'
$replace = 'something to replace string B with'
$countModified = 0


Get-ChildItem $Folderpath -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object {
  if (
    (
      ($_ | Select-String -Pattern $searchStrings).Pattern | Select-Object -Unique
    ).Count -eq $searchStrings.Count
  ) {
    ($_ | Get-Content -Raw) -replace $searchStrings[1], $replace |
      Set-Content $_.FullName
    ++$countModified
    write-host "File Changed: " $_    
  }
}

if ($countModified -eq 0) {
  Write-Host "no files changed"
}
```

- A *single* [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) call is used to determine if *all* pattern match (the solution scales to any number of patterns):

  - Each [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) output object has a `.Pattern` property that indicates which of the patterns passed to `-Pattern` matched on a given line.
  - If, after removing duplicates with `Select-Object -Unique`, the number of patterns associated with matching lines is the same as the number of input patterns, you can assume that all input patterns matched (at least once).
- Reading each matching file *as a whole* with `Get-Content`'s `-Raw` switch and therefore performing only a *single* `-replace` operation per file is much faster than line-by-line processing.